# Total average curvature of a surface?

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, differential-geometry, area

Given a surface $S$ at any point $P$ of $S$ 2 curvatures are defined, the Gaussian curvature, which is the product of the principal curvatures, and the average curvature, which is their arithmetic average.

This is however at a single point, I am wondering if there is a way to define the total/average curvature of a surface. For example as:

$$\frac{1}{A}\int k_1k_2 dS$$

i.e. the surface integral of the gaussian curvature divided by the area of the surface.

Comment: Sure, why not? You could try it on some example surface and see what happens. It's always more interesting to try something yourself, especially when the idea came to you

Comment: @Yuval Why would I remove the $1/A$?

Comment: @Yuval: You didn't read the post. Why do you think we have to see Gauss-Bonnet here? It makes perfectly good sense to ask for the average value of a function on a surface. It's true that what the OP is looking at is *not* topological or scale-invariant.

Comment: As Ted says it should not be scale invariant since, for example, the curvature of a sphere is dependent on its radius.